# Why is 'allopathy' not an accepted synonym for 'mainstream medicine'?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allopathic_medicine),

> Allopathic medicine and *allopathy* (from the Greek prefix ἄλλος, állos, "other", "different" + the suffix πάϑος, páthos, "suffering") are terms coined in the early 19th century by Samuel Hahnemann,the founder of homeopathy, as a synonym for mainstream medicine.
>
> Never accepted as a mainstream scientific term, it was adopted by alternative medicine advocates to refer pejoratively to mainstream medicine.

One will, however, come across the terms, *allopathy* or *allopathic* quite often in India – where *homeopathy* and *ayurveda* therapies have gained big popularity recently, so much that a majority of language purists regard *allopathy* as mainly an Indian English term (– I read that in a magazine recently). That may be subject to argument, but *'allopathy'* does seem to be a term that many across the world refuse use in referring to *mainstream medicine*.

What I would like to know is: Why is *allopathy* not acceptable as a term in that sense? And personally, do you use it to refer to *mainstream medicine* or is there a different term you prefer?

Comment: Perhaps it's because people don't know what "allopathy" means, and "mainstream medicine" is more descriptive.

Comment: @JoeZeng: I disagree. If that is the case, people would rather use 'alternative medicine' for _homeopathy_ because 'alternative medicine' is more descriptive.

Comment: The hypernym for homeopathy, ayurveda, acupuncture, etc., _is_ [alternative medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_medicine). Most if not all alternative practices are also not evidence-based medicine with requirements such as clinical trials etc..

Comment: I'd say it could also be because *osteopathy* is also widely considered to be part of mainstream medicine, but people don't know what that is, either.

Comment: To paraphrase Tim Minchin, it's probably because we already have a name for allopathic medicine: it's 'medicine'.

Comment: I'm confused about this. A student recently emailed me her application essay for a postbac premed program, and she used "allopathic." I didn't know the word, but I found the WP article, which made it sound like a clearly pejorative term. I warned the student that she might be making a big mistake, and she thanked me but said that that was the term used by the school itself: http://www.fullerton.edu/health_professions/professionalschool/allopathic.asp Googling turned up another school in this area that uses the term the same way: http://www.chapman.edu/scst/pre-health-program/helpful-links.aspx

Comment: Johns Hopkins has one of the top-ranked medical schools in the U.S. They have a web page http://web.jhu.edu/prepro/health/allopathic.html that explains the history of the term and states without qualification, "M.D.s practice allopathic medicine." It appears to be used non-pejoratively simply to describe what MD's do, in contradistinction to dentists, pharmacists, physical therapists, and others. The talk page of the WP article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Allopathic_medicine suggests that the term may be politicized or controversial, or maybe just that WP is being dysfunctional here.

Comment: A google ngrams search on the word "allopathic" shows a big spike in the 19th century, after which the word fell into almost complete disuse, followed by a revival in the second half of the 20th century. A google book search for the 19th century shows nearly 100% usage in contradistinction to homeopathy. 20th-century usage seems much more varied. Sometimes it's used in contradistinction to osteopathy, sometimes just as a synonym for "what an MD does." It seems to be used more in India than the rest of the English-speaking world.

Comment: "Allopathy" is a term that homeopathic practitioners use in a pejorative sense to mean "mainstream medicine".  Some "mainstream" folks may embrace it, but I'd be a little careful about using the term.

Comment: In other European nations, the cognates allopathie/homéopathie (Fr,De) are used in pharmacies to distinguish between science based medicine and non-traditional medicines (herbal supplements/non-SBM). 'Allopathy' just didn't catch on in the UK/US. Why could be speculation or could be determined by corpus based research which may be too laborious for a quick ELU answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a start, the reasoning is incorrect:

Strictly *homoeopathy* means "treating like with like". That is to say, you treat an ailment with a medicine that would in other circumstances cause the same symptoms.

Generally though, by *homoeopathy* we mean something narrower still, which is the use of extreme dilutions.

But if we take the word at its root, we could argue that conventional vaccines are "homoeopathic" in this non-specific sense.

*Allopathy* is the exact opposite - treating something with something that causes the opposite effect. You could reasonably apply the term to some conventional approaches (running your finger under a cold tap if you've burnt it is an allopathic remedy!), but not to all of them.

If we take this broad approach to these terms, we can find ourselves applying either depending on how precisely we look. We could consider digitalis. Overdosing on digitalis can cause fatal heart disturbances. Do we consider its use to treat heart conditions homoeopathic (treating heart conditions with something that causes heart conditions) or do we note its antiarrhythmic effects are what cause such fatal heart disturbances and so use it to treat people with heart conditions that would benefit from those effects - essentially an allopathic use.

(Amusingly, digitalis **is** used by both conventional and homoeopathic practitioners to treat some heart conditions).

Most importantly though, not only are not all conventional treatments "allopathic" in this broad sense, but that is not how doctors and medical researchers consider their field. They do not look at a symptom and then immediately concentrate upon looking for various things in the word that cause the opposite to occur.

As such, *allopathic* is inappropriate to use to describe conventional medicine not just on conventional medicine's terms, but on Hahnemann's too.

Comment: Just as a matter of curiosity, can you please explain why you are using the alternative spelling *[homoeopathy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homoeopathy)* instead of the standard spelling *[homeopathy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homeopathy#Noun)* as used in the question?

Comment: @jwpat: I expect to stress the  homoe- prefix (”similar”) from the Ancient Greek ὅμοιος (homoios, “of like kind”, “similar”). Similar to homo-.

Comment: @jwpat7 I have no strong feelings on the word, so just went with what my en-GB spell-check suggests (Firefox does not offer a separate en-IE spell-check). I imagine they assumed *oe* was always favoured over *e* in en-GB when both exist - not always true, but often the case. Incidentally, the only homeopathic pharmacist I regularly pass is labelled *homœopathic*, *homeopathic* and *homoeopathic* on the outside on different signs and posters.

Comment: Of course, while a homeopathic dilution may include digitalis on the label, it's so dilute that there won't be any actual digitalis remaining in the solution.

Comment: @tinyd Yep, though I only address the question of whether it's "like with like" or "like with unlike" because that's the only factor that relates to the coinage *homeopathy* as a coinage.

Comment: For the reasons given in comments, I think this answer is an oversimplification.

Comment: @BenCrowell really? If anything I over-analysed because I addressed the logical flaw in the term. Really, the simpler answer of "because they just don't give a crap what homoeopaths say, so why would they bother using their terms" suffices.

Comment: @JonHanna: Did you read my comments?

Comment: @BenCrowell ah, I see your comments on the question. That is interesting; I haven't seen such uses in anything later than mid-20th Century myself. It would be interesting to see what a wider search turned up (i.e. where the rest of the remaining hits in ngrams is coming from).

Comment: The opposite of homeopathy is not allopathy. It's enantiopathy. Allopathy refers to treatments which cause neither like nor opposite effects.